# Run msbuild task before ccnet generates the label

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, build-process, cruisecontrol.net

The exact sequence of ccnet operations(taken from [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/FAQ)):

```
   1) Wait for the triggers to awaken.
   2) Ask the source control system for a list of the modifications since the last build.
   3) If any modifications were found or if the triggers said "force the build":
           3.1) Generate a label for the build.
           3.2) Run the prebuild tasks in the order specified, failing the build in case of error.
           3.3) Get the source code from the source control system.
           3.4) Run the build tasks in the order specified, failing the build in case of error.
           3.5) If the repository should be labeled:
                   3.5.1) Let the source control system apply the label.
           3.6) Run the publisher tasks.
   4) Go to 1.
```

Is there a way to run some msbuild task before step 3.1 is executed in ccnet.

**Problem Statement**:

I am using "fileLabeller" to display the content of a file in ccnet label. If the file exists this works good. But lets say by any chance the file doesn't exist, then i want to call a msbuild task which creates this file and sets up some dummy text.

I called this msbuild task in prebuild event but to my dismay this didn't work out as label generation happens before prebuild.

Is there a way to call this msbuild task before label generation takes place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cruisecontrol.net will log all output to a file with a specific label. This means that a label has to be determined before anything else happens. 
If you need to run Msbuild to build a label, you might need to write your own labeller.

Comment: Thanks Simon.I wrote a custom labeller for this one.